# JQuery - Object [object Object] has no method

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Hello I am facing this strange JQuery problem. My Js:

```
$("#flip-counter").centerH();
function centerH() {
var marginL = ( $(window).width() - $(this).width() ) / 2;
$(this).css("marginLeft",marginL+"px");
alert(marginL);
}
```

Getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'centerH'         
(anonymous function) 

k jquery.js:2 
l.fireWith jquery.js:2 
p.extend.ready jquery.js:2
D jquery.js:2
```

jquery.js:2 is empty.

I would understand if none of the code would work but now everything works except that and I can't add any other function. I just keep getting the same error. All files are included properly and when I delete this piece of JS code, my code works like a charm.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code:

```
$("#flip-counter").centerH()
```

...tries to get a property called `centerH` from the jQuery object returned by `$("#flip-counter")` and then call it as a function. So there has to be a `centerH` function on the object.

This code:

```
function centerH() {
var marginL = ( $(window).width() - $(this).width() ) / 2;
$(this).css("marginLeft",marginL+"px");
alert(marginL);
}
```

...creates a `centerH` function but does nothing whatsoever to add it to jQuery.

If you're trying to make a [jQuery plug-in](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring), you assign the function to `$.fn`:

```
$.fn.centerH = centerH;
```

Once you've done that, the `$("#flip-counter").centerH()` line will work. But note that in a jQuery plug-in function, `this` is **not** a DOM element (your `$(this).css(...)` code seems to be treating it as one). Within a jQuery plug-in function, `this` is the jQuery object on which the function was called (so `this.css(...)` instead).

Comment: I never really used this and done lots of JQuery before, this is not a plugin, just a function in js file which is used for frontend. Surpisingly, this does work like that just somehow doesnt return anything - alaerts 0, but maybe that is my problem, Thank you.

Comment: @RokasPetrošius: If you're not doing a plugin, then `$("#flip-counter").centerH()` is not how you call it, and will give you exactly the error you describe. Of course, `$("#flip-counter").click(centerH)` or something would be a different story.

Answer (score 6):

You need to extend the jquery,if you want to use the function with jquery objects.

```
$.fn.centerH = function() {
    var marginL = ( $(window).width() - $(this).width() ) / 2;
    $(this).css("marginLeft",marginL+"px");
    alert(marginL);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The centerH() function is in the global scope. But you're calling it from the $("#flip-counter") jQuery object.

If you want to make your own custom functions available to jQuery objects you would create it like this:

```
jQuery.fn.yourFunction = function() { 
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Tried this, the result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add functions to JQuery like that.  You will need to add it as a plugin using jQuery.fn.centerH

More info on:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring